# win 10 iot cant login after changing password

Tags: windows-iot

- I downloaded the raspi image from MS.
- I have the issue where my computer thinks my admin is blocking the iot dashboard so I used the dism workaround to flash the sd card.
- Device boots with defaults and I can log in via powershell as detailed in the MS docs. Administrator/p@ssw0rd
- I change machine name using

`set computername mycoolname`

- Then I create a new account for myself and add it to the local admin group.

`net user ME awesomepass`

- Then I change the default admin password and reset.

`net user Administrator coolpass`

When the raspi comes back up the hostname is still minwinpc(the defualt name) and neither the built in admin account or the new one I created will work. 
I tried the default password and the one I changed it to.

Anyone else have these issues? Ive tried waiting on the device to settle in, as others have reported that it can take time. Its not making a difference.